# I don't want my DHCP to be a default gateway

Tags: ip, routing, dhcp, gateway, dnsmasq

I have a device which runs a DHCP server. When I connect it with USB to my computer, the PC gets an IP address and the device becomes the default gateway. I just want the device to agree on IP addresses and not default gateway. Is this possible?

I was using udhcpd but I got problems with authoritative mode so I switched to dnsmasq.

The PC is already connected to another network witch should contain the default gateway.

EDIT :

Here is a little diagram of how it is setup

[ Embedded Network #1 ]  -----  [ PC ] ----- [ Corporate Network #2 ]

What is important here is that Net#1 has no knowledge of Net#2, its dhcp server and its default gateway

EDIT 2 :

Ok, the parameter in /etc/dnsmasq.conf should be about dhcp-option=3
If I don't specify this parameter well, there is no effect. According to [this example config](http://pyramidlinux.googlecode.com/svn-history/r158/Pyramid/dist/etc/dnsmasq.conf).

```
# Disable default gateway
#dhcp-option=3
```

This does not disable the gateway, this has no effect

EDIT 3 :

ok dhcp-option=3 DOES have an effect (Silly me). However just renewing ip is not enough for windows xp to forget about the old one

Comment: May I ask what did you do for Windows to forget about the old one?

Comment: Although being a little late, just for the reference, you can use `ipconfig /release` followed by a `ipconfig /renew` to make Windows forget about the old settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly possible - just reconfigure the device to not hand out a gateway over DHCP.

You probably need to provide more information to get a useful response.

add to the conf file

```
dhcp-option=3
dhcp-option=6
```

3 disables default router (gateway) and 6 disables DNS

Comment: What kind of information?

Comment: What's the device? Can you reconfig dhcp on it? Or is this enough?

Comment: It is a custom embedded device which runs linux. I can cross compile a lot of stuff for ARM for it. I can of course edit configs

Comment: You need to change DHCP option 3 (Router) to point to your router.  DHCP is often handled by the router, so is is usually to have the DHCP configuration to default the router setting to its address.

Comment: Bill, I edited my question. The device network does not know the other network

Comment: Just disable the option that provides a default gateway to the dhcp client.

Comment: Wolfie, there is no such options. It is done by default with dnsmasq. I want the option NOT to give one